# Calling class methods from class body

Tags: python

I have the code something like:

```
class ClassPrintable:

    @classmethod
    def print_class(cls):
        print(cls)
```

I would like to be able to derive classes from this, and furthermore call the class methods inline from the class body, eg.

```
class MyClass(ClassPrintable):

    print_class()
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, however this does:

```
class MyClass(ClassPrintable):

    ClassPrintable.print_class()
```

Unfortunately, of course, it prints the class for `ClassPrintable` rather than `MyClass`

The obvious solution, doesn't work, eg.

```
class MyClass(ClassPrintable):

    MyClass.print_class()
```

Python complains it can't find `MyClass`! with a `NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined`

How can I access `MyClass`'s class method from within the body of its definition? I would prefer not to use dynanic metaprogramming but I will if I have to.

Comment: Have you checked https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__?

Comment: Can't reproduce (fixed): https://repl.it/repls/GenuineSimplisticIntelligence

Comment: Your're close, but I want MyClass.print_class() to be called inline in the class body

Comment: There *is no* `MyClass` class during the execution of its class body. The class only comes into existence afterward. Even if you were to screw with the class namespace to make `print_class` available by that name, there would be no class object to provide as `cls`.

Comment: What you are asking for does not make sense - there is no class at the point you want to use it. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot invoke anything on the class before it exists which is only *after* the class definition (note that method bodies aren't evaluated at class definition time). In Python >= 3.6, you can do the following, using the [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__) hook:

```
class ClassPrintable:
    @classmethod
    def print_class(cls):
        print(cls)

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        cls.print_class()

class MyClass(ClassPrintable):
    pass
```

Comment: This seems to achieve a different goal from what the question asks for.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica It seems to me that the OP wants to execute a class method once upon the creation of each subclass of the `ClassPrintable` class. This does achieve that.

Comment: It seems to me that the OP wants to be able to call inherited class methods inside a class body. The question shows no desire to make the method call automatically happen exactly once for each subclass.

Comment: I would like to create a `Models` class with getters and setters like properties except supporting validating the properties for appropriate values, and the observer pattern to monitor the changing models. Looks like you're right I can't add properties to the class inline with its definition, I'll have to use `__init_subclass__` somehow.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Calling a method inside the class body appears to me to be the equivalent of wanting to execute it once upon class creation.

Comment: I wanted to do things like `add_model("x") add_model("y") add_model("visible") etc. on the class. The class itself keeps track of observers of the models, and each instance of the class gets attributes x, y, visible etc. Looks like I'll have to delve into metaprogramming.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: For one thing, wanting to be *able* to call inherited class methods inside the class body is very different from wanting to *force* subclasses to call the method. For another, there could be multiple calls, or conditional calls, or calls in a loop. The timing of the call(s) relative to the rest of the class body may also be important.

Comment: (Judging by the latest comment, there would indeed be multiple calls.)

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out with small amount of metaprogramming. Whoever thought of `__init_subclass__` is a genius. If anyone can see anything drastically wrong with this let me know.

```
import copy

class Model:

    def __init__(self, name, default):
        self.model_name = name
        self.model_default = default
        self.observers = []

class Models():

    model_dictionary = {}

    def __init_subclass__(cls, models=[]):
        setattr(cls, "model_dictionary", {})
        for model in models:
            cls.model_dictionary[model[0]] = Model(model[0], model[1])
        for c in cls.__bases__:
            cls.add_base_models(c)

    @classmethod
    def add_base_models(cls, base):
        if hasattr(base, "model_dictionary"):
            for model in base.model_dictionary.values():
                cls.model_dictionary[model.model_name] = copy.copy(base.model_dictionary[model.model_name])
        for c in base.__bases__:
            cls.add_base_models(c)


    @classmethod
    def listen(cls, name, closure):
        cls.model_dictionary[name].observers.append(closure)

    def __init__(self):
        for model in self.model_dictionary.values():
            super().__setattr__(model.model_name, model.model_default)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in self.__class__.model_dictionary.keys():
            orig_value = getattr(self, name)
            if value != orig_value:
                for observer in self.model_dictionary[name].observers:
                    observer(self, value)
                super().__setattr__(name, value)
        else:
            super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

Sample use of the code:

```
class Mouse(Models, models=[("x", 100), ("y", 200), ("visible", True)]):
    pass

class SpecialMouse(Mouse, models=[("anger_level", "hostile")]):
    pass

mouse = SpecialMouse()

mouse.listen("anger_level", lambda mouse, value : print(value))

mouse.anger_level = "cold!"
mouse.anger_level = "warm"
mouse.anger_level = "warm"
mouse.anger_level = "furious"
```

Prints out:

```
cold!
warm
furious
```